# Excel template migration from JXLS 1 to JXLS 2

Tags: java, excel, jxls

With JXLS 1 it was possible to make replacements within an Excel template through a simple invocation to

```
XLSTransformer.transformXLS(is,beans)
```

For example, we had bean objects which were organized something like this (not so nice, ok..:)):

```
class Person{
private String name;
private String lastname;
private String tel;
private String gender;
private Integer count;

public Person(String name, String lastname, String telephone, String gender){
this.name = name;
this.lastname = lastname;
this.tel = telephone;
this.gender = gender;
this.count = null;
}

public Person(String gender, int count){
this.gender = gender;
this.count = count;
}
//getters
}
```

Now, given this template:

[image: template]

and the following initialization:

```
List<Person> p = Arrays.asList(
new Person(„Johnny“, „Cash“, „1394567“, „M“),
new Person(„Paul“, „Newman“, „234667“, „M“),
new Person(„M“,2),
new Person(„Jessica“, „Alba“, „134566“, „F“),
new Person(„F“,1)
); 

Map<String, List<? extends Object>> beans = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Object>>();
beans.put(„persons“, p);
beans.put(„heading“, Arrays.asList(„This is the heading“));
```

a simple call to

```
transformer.transformXLS(templateInputStream, beans);
```

would have done the trick and generated something like this:

[image: generated XLS]

Now, I needed to migrate to JXLS 2 in order to use SXSSFWorkbook for very big XLSX files, but I couldn't succeed to translate the good old tags into their comment equivalent: in the online-doc I read that it's possible to combine more expression together, but for example something like ***jx:each*** followed by a ***jx:if*** which uses the loop’s variable would generate an expression EvaluationException.

Do you have any hints / examples which may help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A template example combining *jx:each* and *jx:if* commands can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/raw/92cfcc8ee6e2f810a061b8b7b3afd3a228e966bc/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/comment_markup_demo.xls) and looks like this

[image: jxls template with combining jx:each and jx:if]

Java code is in [jxls-demo project](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/92cfcc8ee6e2f810a061b8b7b3afd3a228e966bc/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/XlsCommentBuilderDemo.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Try to use this approach.

If after this you still have an issue in implementing your case in JXLS-2 please raise an improvement in JXLS issue tracker.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast reply! I tried several combination but still don't get what I want and don't understand the problem. If my jx:each indicates as lastCell the equivalent of C14 (the count for Female) I get empty lines between data rows, if I specify the equivalent of C5 (the end of the first row with dynamic data in the new format) each row is blue and the count is not displayed. Furthermore, which "else" area should I use for the last jx:if row? Thanks